# GET lambda function using postman (authorization header)

Tags: aws-lambda, postman, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to do simple GET lambda function via postman using API gateway.I'm getting 200 OK using authorization code in lambda function but
I want to pass authorization token when calling from postman

```js
exports.handler = async(event)  => {

    try {
        const res = await axios.get('https://hellothere.com/1435',{
           headers : {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer XXXXXXX',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
           }
        })
        console.log(res)
        
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(res.data)
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        return {
            statusCode: 400,
            body: JSON.stringify(e)
        }
    } 


};
```

I don't want to give Authorization token in the code instead when I can call from postman I want to pass the token

Comment: What options do you see in postman for specifying a header?

Comment: solution : try {
        const res = await axios.get('https://hellothere.com/1435',{
           headers : {
    'Authorization': 'event.headers.Authorization',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
           }
        })